# I can't add new object to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two models: Stage and Quiz

```
public class Stage
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid StageId { get; set; }

    (...)

    public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}

public class Quiz
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Stage")]
    public Guid StageId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }

    public Quiz()
    {

        Questions = new List<Question>();
        Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

and Create method:

```
public Guid Create(NewQuizViewModel quizToCreate)
    {
        Stage currentStage = _stageService.GetStageById(quizToCreate.StageId);

        List<Question> newQuestions = new List<Question>();

        foreach (var question in quizToCreate.Questions)
        {
            Question newQuestion = new Question();
            newQuestion.QuestionId = Guid.NewGuid();
            newQuestion.QuestionContent = question.QuestionContent;
            newQuestion.Answers = question.Answers;
            newQuestion.CorrectAnswer = question.CorrectAnswer;
            newQuestions.Add(newQuestion);
        }

        Quiz quizToDatabase = new Quiz()
        {
            Questions = newQuestions,
            Stage = currentStage,
        };

        _dbContext.Quizzes.Add(quizToDatabase);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return quizToDatabase.StageId;
    }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with the code? I can't add Quiz to database, StageId is empty. I have error in line

```
_dbContext.Quizzes.Add(quizToDatabase);
```

Screenshot:
[Adding to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ClCr.png)

In Seed method everything is ok.

```
var quizzes = new List<Quiz>()
        {
            new Quiz()
            {
                Questions = new List<Question>()
                {
                    new Question()
                    {
                        QuestionContent = "Just mark 1st",
                        Answers = new List<string>(4)
                        {
                            "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"
                        },
                        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer.FirstAnswer
                    },
                    new Question()
                    {
                        QuestionContent = "Just mark 3rd",
                        Answers = new List<string>(4)
                        {
                            "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"
                        },
                        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer.ThirdAnswer
                    },
                    new Question()
                    {
                        QuestionContent = "Just mark 4th",
                        Answers = new List<string>(4)
                        {
                            "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"
                        },
                        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer.FourthAnswer
                    }
                },
                Stage = context.Stages.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name=="Stage Example")

            }
        };

        quizzes.ForEach(c => context.Quizzes.Add(c));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

I can't see the difference. Thanks for help

Comment: Does `Stage currentStage = _stageService.GetStageById(quizToCreate.StageId);` find a stage?

Comment: Yes, even in the picture object quizToDatabase has Stage but not StageId

Comment: What is the error? Post the full exception (including the call stack) in the *question*. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/j1YXBCPz

Comment: @Dre **in the *question***, not a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because You get "currentStage" from "_stageService" (first dbcontext!) and SaveChanges on "_dbContext" (second dbcontext).
You cannot mix dbContext...